# Suggestions for troubleshooting this Perl DBD::mysql error message?

Tags: mysql, perl, module

"Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect() of DBD::mysql::db"

Unable to find any documentation related to the error, any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your db connection, usually the `$dbh` in plain DBI code, needs to be disconnected before it goes out of scope. See [DBI#disconnect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#disconnect) and try putting "dbi disconnect" into google/etc to see related issues discussions.

Comment: +1 Great thanks, I'll look into info related to dbi disconnect.

Answer (score 5):

It's important to do commit/rollback (i.e `$dbh->commit;`)after the insert/update/delete sentences in your SQL code, because you pass `{Autocommit=>0}` parameter in the database connection code. And, of course, you must do `$dbh->disconnect` before you finish your program